# Aggregate rows into complex json - Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I've an Athena query which gives me the below table for a given IDs:

| ID | ID_2 | description | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | abc | [MN, SD] |
| Second | row | xyz | [AL, CA ] |

I'm using the `array_agg` function to merge states into an array. Within the query itself I want convert the output into the format below:

| ID | ID_2 | custom_object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | {'description': 'abc', 'state': ['MN', 'SD']} |

I'm looking at the Athena docs but haven't found function that does just this. I'm experimenting with `multimap_agg` and `map_agg` but this seems to be too complex to achieve. How can I do this, please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it after aggregation by combining casts to json and creating map:

```
-- sample data
WITH dataset (ID, ID_2, description, state) AS (
    VALUES ('First',    'row',  'abc',  array['MN', 'SD']),
    ('Second',  'row',  'xyz',  array['AL', 'CA' ])
) 

-- query
select ID,
    ID_2,
    cast(
        map(
            array [ 'description',
            'state' ],
            array [ cast(description as json),
            cast(state as json) ]
        ) as json
    ) custom_object
from dataset
```

Output:

| ID | ID_2 | custom_object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | {"description":"abc","state":["MN","SD"]} |
| Second | row | {"description":"xyz","state":["AL","CA"]} |